Understand how Spark cache-aware compuation works
I am reading following article about Cache-aware Computation:
https://www.databricks.com/blog/2015/04/28/project-tungsten-bringing-spark-closer-to-bare-metal.html
It provides a picture as below showing that key-pointer pair structure can help for the cache-aware computation/sorting.
But, in the key-pointer pair, Spark still needs to refer to the remote value object in the main memory which still leads to cache loss, so I don't understand how cache aware works here.
Using a key-pointer pair, how should cache-aware computation work?

https://www.databricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Screen-Shot-2015-04-27-at-6.12.51-PM.png
